# How to store the data into json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have passing the array with object. Then this data have to be store that arrays within than object.

I have passing like this.

```
response.resp = [...]
insertBranch("one", response.resp);
```

So, In that method,

```
function insertBranch(name,info){
    this.jfsInfo.branches[name] = info;
}
```

It have to come like

```
jfsInfo.branches= {
"one":[...]
}
```

If i pass

```
insertBranch("two", response.resp);
```

It have create two object automatically and that array have to be stored in that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code , It may help you

```
<script>
var a = [1,2,3, 'a', 'b'];
    var jfsInfo={};
    insertBranch("two", a);
    function insertBranch(value, array)
    {
        if(value=="one")
        {
            jfsInfo.branches={};
            jfsInfo.branches.one=array;
        }
        else if(value=="two")
        {
           jfsInfo.branches={};
           jfsInfo.branches.one=array;
           jfsInfo.branches.two=array;
        }
    }

    console.log(jfsInfo.branches);

</script>
```